# How can I get access to a Apache ECharts through id of DOM-Container?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I draw many piecharts on the map, at some point in time I need to update those piecharts using `setOption`. All I found they suggest saving the echart object inside the variable then update base on variables like below:

```
//Create
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.getElementById("someId"));
    ...
};
//Update
echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

But this is not working for me because I have many echart instances and I should match them base on their `id` like below:

```
//It is not updating but I want something like that for updating echarts
someFunctionOrInstance("#echartId").setOption(option)
```

As I know, this approach is doable with other chart libraries like `chart.js`

Comment: `setOption` is a method of the object that `echarts.init` returned, but `$("#echartId")` returns a jQuery instance. _"But this is not working for me because I have many echart instances"_ - so store them into an object then, using the ID as key - then you can simply look them up in the object via that same ID ...?

Comment: Is there any way besides saving inside object? Can we return echart instance using identifer (id, class, name) or there is no such ways?!

Comment: I'm guessing https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.getInstanceByDom could do that (not _directly_ via ID, you need to pass in a div or canvas element, but _those_ you can select via their ID first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setOption` is a method of the object that `echarts.init` returned, but `$("#echartId")` returns a jQuery instance.

One option would be to store these into an object, using the ID as key - then you have easy access to them, directly via that.

The other would be to use the [echarts.getInstanceByDom](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.getInstanceByDom) method - that does not select by ID directly, but needs to get a div or canvas element passed in, and will then return the correct instance for that element.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.echartid.setOption(option)
```

this will do.